# Recommended Laravel route structure for model relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

I know this question might be entirely opinion based but here goes. I would like to know the recommended way to structure routes based on model relationships in Laravel. Take for example the following three models:

```
User
Post
Comment
```

With their relationship (at the most basic) as follows:

```
User hasMany Posts
Post hasMany Comments
```

In my rotes file, I wish to get a list of Posts by a specific User. I might be inclined to use any of the following:

```
Route::get('/users/{user_id}/posts')
Route::get('/posts/{user_id}')
```

And also for fetching comments of a particular post I can use any of the two:

```
Route::get('/posts/{post_id}/comments')
Route::get('/comments/{post_id}')
```

Which method would be termed most recommended. And why? Thank you all!

Comment: If you're in `/posts/{post_id}` and you can click on a comment to view details then appending the comment id to your current URL makes more sense since it looks like you're navigating a tree structure rather than jumping around. In general it depends on your navigation structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first alternatives looks good:

```
Route::get('/users/{userId}/posts')
Route::get('/posts/{postId}/comments')
```

If you want to implement "the inverse" endpoint, how about more explicitly describing the route parameters:

```
Route::get('/posts/by-user/{userId}')
Route::get('/comments/for-post/{postId}')
```

Comment: Thanks you @Anders. That definitely steers me into the right direction.